# populated jquery objects show as undefined when passed

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following script, although the two weather objects are both populated with data in the ajax calls, the updateWeather call shows them both as undefined prior to that line executing. I moved the variable declarations so they would be global but they still both show undefined prior to the updateWeather call. What am I missing? Can I not set up a variable in the ajax success function and then pass it later?
***Note: If you want to test this use a different url as this one won't work for you with out my credentials***

```
function getWeatherForecastStationCode() {
var d = new Date();
var parts = d.toString().split(" ");
var dDate = parts[1] + " " + parts[2] + ", " + parts[3];
var ampm;
if (parts[4].split(":")[0] <= 12) {
    ampm = "AM";
} else {
    ampm = "PM";
}
var dtime = parts[4].split(":")[0] + ":" + parts[4].split(":")[1];
var datetime = dDate + " " + dtime + ampm;
alert(datetime);
var weatherStation = "KPBI";  // get from GetWeatherService.svc
var forecastFields = "&fields=periods.maxTempF%2cperiods.minTempF%2cperiods.vaildTime%2cperiods.weather%2cperiods.icon";
var currentFields = "&fields=ob.tempC%2cob.tempF%2cob.icon%2cplace.name%2cplace.state";
var forecastUrlWeatherStation = 'http://api.aerisapi.com/forecasts/' + weatherStation + '?limit=1&client_id=' + AerisClientId + '&client_secret=' + AerisWeatherApiSecret + forecastFields;
var currentUrlWeatherStation = 'http://api.aerisapi.com/observations/' + weatherStation + '?limit=1&client_id=' + AerisClientId + '&client_secret=' + AerisWeatherApiSecret + currentFields;


$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: forecastUrlWeatherStation,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (json) {
        if (json.success === true) {
            forecastedWeather = {
                weather: json.response[0].periods[0].weather,
                maxTemp: json.response[0].periods[0].maxTempF,
                minTemp: json.response[0].periods[0].minTempF,
                weatherIcon: json.response[0].periods[0].icon,
                obsTime: datetime
            };
        }
        else {
            alert('An error occurred: ' + json.error.description);
        }
    }
});
var location;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: currentUrlWeatherStation,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (json) {
        if (json.success === true) {
            var place = json.response.place.name.split(" ");
            if (place.length === 1) {
               location = place[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + place[0].substr(1, place[0].length);
            } else {
               location = place[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + place[0].substr(1, place[0].length) + " " + place[1].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + place[1].substr(1, place[1].length) + ", " + json.response.place.state.toUpperCase();
            }
            currentWeather = {
                location: location,
                currentTemp: json.response.ob.tempF
            };
        } else {
            alert('An error occurred: ' + json.error.description);
        }
    }
});   
updateWeather(forecastedWeather,currentWeather);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that AJAX is Asynchronous (Thats the "A" in "AJAX"), so the call to `updateWeather` is executing before a response is received from your 2 ajax calls.

The way to do this then, is to wait for all ajax calls to complete before calling `updateWeather`.

Something like the following (untested):

```
$.when(getForecast(),getCurrent()).done(function(f,c){
  updateWeather(forecastedWeather,currentWeather)
});

function getForecast(){
   return $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: forecastUrlWeatherStation,
    dataType: "json"
    ....
    });   
};

function getCurrent(){
   return $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: currentUrlWeatherStation,
    dataType: "json"
    ....
    });   
};
```